# Do people influence how fast the tower goes?

Tags: splatoon-2

Playing tower control you have to stand on a tower to get into the enemy base. Some people stay on the tower and the other go forward and splat people. When someone else is on the tower I usually go forth and splat people. But if there are more people on the tower will the tower go faster?

Comment: If you found the answer to your own question, you should add it as an answer!  There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, and it will help other people who find this question later even if the wiki later goes down or people can't access it for some reason.  Plus given this question already has a few upvotes you'll probably get some extra points from people who appreciate learning this information, like myself :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the [inkpedia page](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Tower_Control) on tower control, it says that

> The tower no longer gains a general speed boost from having multiple Inklings ride it. Instead, the number of Inklings only affects the speed that checkpoints are beaten.

Comment: fascinating!  I could swear it moves faster when more on board.